# Sliding Menu Bar is Working- But Not Well

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've been having a lot of trouble with this menu.  I have it working but the method I'm using is both buggy and inefficient.  Take a look at the jsfiddle, on first hover the pop-up menu does not have any animation.  However, on second hover and every hover after that the desired animation works.  Even if I get it to work on first hover it will still not be well made because when the user tries to access any of the items on the drop down the mouse out event is triggered and the menu begins to slide up.  Here's the Jquery I am using:

```
$(function(){
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideDown(250);
});
$('.dropdown').mouseout(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideUp(250);
});
```

I tried making the mouse out apply to the drop down menu as well by using:

```
$('.dropdown','.dropdown-menu').mouseout(function(){
```

That just made it worse.  I am looking for a more efficient and user-friendly way to make my menu bar have the desired animations.

https://jsfiddle.net/ghcywu6L/

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/ghcywu6L/1/

Comment: your code doesn't seem to be using the slide animation

Comment: did you read the code? it's using the same `$.slideUp()` and `$.slideDown()` you are...

Comment: Yes, I did.  In chrome it displays no animation for me.  I tried in firefox and it still has the same first hover issue as I do.  Really confused by this

Comment: sliding animation works for me on chrome

Comment: works for me, too. your initial example works-ish - the slide animation works fine, but the menu doesn't stay open when you hover over the dropdown itself, though my code should have fixed that.

Comment: Issue must be on my side!  Sorry for that.  Care to put your comment as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Thank you for the help fixing the drop down.  If possible could you explain what the change to the javascript you made does?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this js code

```
$(function(){
$(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("250");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("250");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't know about the `mouseover` thingy. It actually exists. Check out the code. It should be fine now.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown').mouseover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideDown(250);
  });
  $('.dropdown').mouseout(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideUp(250);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Top nav syling */

.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgb(54, 135, 2);
  font-size: 120%;
}


/*Main display styling */

.jumbotron {
  height: 400px;
  background: url("../images/bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 96%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
  border-top: 5px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/*Navbar font coloring */

.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  color: white;
}


/* Centers content vertically */

.vert-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/*Styles partially transparent background within jumbotron class */

.transparent {
  background: rgba(190, 200, 216, .5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 4px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
  border-right: 4px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
  width: 60%;
}


/*Padding around desc within jumbotron */

#heading-desc {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}


/*Padding around title within jumbotron */

#heading-title {
  padding-top: 15px;
}


/* Bootstrap menu created using bootstrapdesigntools.com */

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(54, 135, 2, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 0%, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 0%, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 100%);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(90, 224, 4, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(68, 168, 5, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #44a805;
}


/*Styling of icons */

.size {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}


/*Outline surrounding three columns including icons */

.outline {
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
}

.navbar-bottom {
  background-color: rgba(222, 223, 224, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 223, 224, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 223, 224, 1) 100%);
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.btn-format {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 6%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.horizontal-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}


}
.footer-heading {
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
footer-title-pad {
  padding-top: 2px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(47, 196, 116, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(68, 229, 74, 1);
}

/*Styles active tab of top menu bar */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(57, 145, 3, 1));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(57, 145, 3, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(57, 145, 3, 1) 100%);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #2fc474;
}
.navbar-bottom button {
  margin: auto;
}
.footer-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.footer-top {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

/*Upper outline on bottom navigation bar*/
.outline-above {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
}

/*Spacing between buttons in footer, error- needs more efficient  class */
#button-margin-top1 {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
#button-margin-top2 {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
#button-margin-top3 {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

/*dropdown menu background color */
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: rgba(47, 196, 116, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(67, 171, 3, .93) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, .93) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(67, 171, 3, .93) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, .93) 100%);
}

/*Dropdown menu on hover instead of click unless screen has been resized */
@media (min-width: 979px) {
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover>ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(68, 229, 74, 1);
}

/*Changes dropdown menu icon on screen resize */
.navbar-toggle,
.icon-bar {
  background-color: rgba(44, 226, 50, 1);
}
.dropdown>a {
  display: block;
}
.div-outliner {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-lg-8 {
  background: url("../images/bg.jpg");
  height: 300px;
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dropdown.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle slideDown" data-toggle="dropdown">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 

</body>

</html>
```